# Creating a new VPC and EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I deleted my default VPC to start from scratch with a private network CIDR (10.10.10.0/24). After that I checked all ACL's and security-group settings to be open to the world. I also attached a new internet gateway to my VPC and my EC2 instance is also showing a public IP after launch.
The problem now is that I'm not able to access the public EC2 instance IP using SSH. I have no idea how to further process here, I checked the AWS documentations but with no success as everything seems to be in place as it has to be.

Can smb. please explain to me how to build a VPC from scratch. So that if I launch an EC2 instance within the VPC I can access the public IP of the ec2 instance using SSH

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added route to your internate gateway to your route tables?

Comment: Yes, I have attached a Route to a Subnet and the Subnet again is attached to the VPC

Comment: Can you  provide more details of your setup? SGs, route tables, VPC settings. You can make screenshots if you want.

Comment: What as to be in 
VPC > Route Tables > Edit routes ???
Currently it only shows Destination: 10.10.10./24; Target: local

Comment: Sure give me a second

Comment: You should have a route `0.0.0.0/0` with target of your IGW.

Comment: Check this out: https://cloud.venom.one/s/XKfd7k7NY7CfxEX

Comment: Okay if i try to set the route for 0.0.0.0/0 I get the following error: Route table has a conflicting association with the gateway igw-0c251f718f9bf9876

Comment: Okay just got it working, the issue was related to the edge associations of the route table to the gateway, this option has to be remove in order to set the route ... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused due to **lack of correct route to internet gateway**. The correct route should directed all connections to `0.0.0.0/0` into the gateway.

The **solution** was to provide correct route to the gateway.